# Query to get tags for a user from SEDE

Tags: support, data-explorer

Each user has a tab "TAGS", that basically gives an information in which area of programming the user participated in SO.

What would be query for getting such data, given user id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want to know that from [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/). In that case [tags per user](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/208150/tags-per-user?UserId=578411) would tell you that.

```sql
-- userid: Your user id "Copy from the url"

select distinct t.tagname
from tags t 
inner join posttags pt on pt.tagid = t.id
inner join posts q on pt.postid = q.id
left outer join posts a on a.parentid = q.id
where q.owneruserid = ##userid##
or a.owneruserid = ##userid##
```

Or a clever/ more efficient version from [Deduplicator](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/357308/tags-per-user?UserId=578411)

```sql
-- userid: Your user id "Copy from the url"
select distinct t.tagname
from tags t 
inner join posttags pt on pt.tagid = t.id
inner join posts p on pt.postid in (p.id, p.parentid)
where p.owneruserid = ##userid##
```

Comment: This query seems more efficient: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/357308/tags-per-user?UserId=578411