# What SEDE query can display Posts with a tag matching one of a specific user watched tags?

Tags: support, data-explorer

As of today on Stack Overflow, I have 119 watched tags.

I ran the [Deduplicator query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/357308/tags-per-user?UserId=578411) from [Query to get tags for a user from SEDE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265460/query-to-get-tags-for-a-user-from-sede). It returns [35 tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/357308/tags-per-user?UserId=8864226), of which many are not in my list of watched tags.

I've written a query to locate interesting posts, but more than half of the 30,000 questions have none of my watched tags. I'd like to add an "ignore posts with no watched tags" step.

Is the data not in [SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, the per-user data for watched tags is not in the public schema.

Quoting [Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) to [Let me get my favorite tags using data explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271875):

> You can query Data Explorer for your favorite *questions*, but favorite *tags* are not recorded in the public data.

Unfortunately, Shog9's imagination notwithstanding, the [Stack Exchange API doesn't expose this information, either](https://stackapps.com/questions/8126/stack-exchange-api-get-watched-tags-for-a-user).

I did a quick scan on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/search?q=favorite+%5Bscript%5D+or+%5Bapp%5D) but there doesn't seem to be an app or script that scrapes that info yet. If you do venture into that area, we would love to have your contribution on Stack Apps.

What you can do is manually collect your watched tags and then enter them, semi-colon separated, as a parameter to be included in a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1631566?watched=c%23%3Bjava%3Bsql) like so:

```
select p.id [Post Link]
     , p.creationdate
     , p.score
from posts p
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = p.id
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
inner join string_split(##watched:string##, ';') w on w.value = t.tagname
where p.closeddate is not null
and p.answercount = 0
and p.score > 0 
and p.creationdate between '2022-01-01'  and getdate()
order by p.score desc
```

Comment: So if I scraped them, how could I write a SQL to where (post tag in my scraped list of my tags = true) filter? Should I write a new question since this is a secondary question?

Comment: If you scrape you're on your own. How you deal with the scraped data or how you post process it, is 100% up to you.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping. I would personally not go to a database with my scraped data, but just shape and filter while scraping as you have plenty of time between network calls.

Comment: To clarify, I would manually copy the tags and have a text list of them. Once that list is in hand could I use a bunch of likes to compare them to the tags on the current post?

Comment: So after "-- with one of my tags" in https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1631537/open-unanswered-high-views-low-voted-high-reputation?UserId=8864226 ?

Comment: That sounds more like you need a userscript. I'm a bit time constrained right now but I'll try to ping someone who might have ideas on that.